# REST & SOAP API parsing to Flutter

Tags: api, rest, flutter, soap

I'm learning to build my first app using `Flutter`. This will replace a very functional but rudimentary app that I built using `Appsheets` in combination with `Google Sheets docs`. The app will perform a number of tasks for my business. To start things off I'm needing to connect to our ERP systems REST API to get and post various information.

[api-docs.brightpearl.com](http://api-docs.brightpearl.com)

I would also be wanting to get and post from our courier service `SOAP API`

```
collivery.net/integration/api/soap
```

I'm fully prepared to invest the time in reading, learning, and experimenting on this project in order to get it right rather than simply palming it off to a dev company as I see huge value in learning these skills myself.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn how to read JSON because now days most REST send JSON format, if you already know that jump to flutter learn the basics, if you Already  know how  to creat simple flutter app, you probably ready to start working, go ahead and learn flutter 
http package, this will help you contact your REST to get and post data 
https://pub.dev/packages/http
or

Dio this will help you contact your REST to get and post data
https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Im not sure if this is enough for you to start with